# Is there a way to pull posts by the date they appear on the timeline? Like from 1987?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, history, facebook-timeline

On the Facebook timeline, you can set the date an event happened. Like when you were born, married, really anything. However, when using the API, it only searches on the created date.

Example: If I create an event today and set the date to March 18, 1987, it shows up on my timeline properly, but the API pulls it out as an event that happened today as its 'created date' is today.

Is there a way to pull posts by the date they appear on the timeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way yet to retrieve life events yet.  You only can retrieve the status that it's been added to his/her timeline. However, you may try to get the date from story string using RegEx or substring...